# Best place to ask this question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

I have a semi-programming orientated question in that it is to do with my programming workflow and automation of the programs that I use, would this be okay to post up on SO?

Comment: You don't need permission from meta. Try it and see. If you're worried about subjectivity, try and generalise the problem as much as you can, and avoid asking for opinions (even if the answer may be someone's opinion).

Comment: @ire_and_curses Cool will do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this similar question

[Choosing between stackoverflow.com and programmers.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stackoverflow-com-and-programmers-stackexchange-com/82990#82990)

Comment: this: `software tools commonly used by programmers` seems to match my question so SO is the right place, I just think it may be closed as subjective even though it is about programming tools.